# Dividing numbers

Tags: java, math

Division of two numbers using arithmetic operators in Java.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Write a number: ");
String mataett = scan.next();
System.out.print("Write a number: ");
String matatva = scan.next();

int nr1 = Integer.parseInt(mataett);
int nr2 = Integer.parseInt(matatva);
System.out.println(Math.round(nr1 / nr2*10.0)/10.0);
```

When I run this with `73/27` I get the answer `2.0`, but what I want to get is the answer `2.7`

Comment: Integer division.

Comment: Integer division.

Comment: when you divide 2 integers, the answer is an integer which is always rounder down (2.9 = 2 and 2.1 = 3). cast into doubles and then divide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When I run this with 73/27 I get the answer 2.0, but what I want to
>   get is the answer 2.7

The reason being you're getting the unexpected result is because when you divide by integers, the result is always an integer, which means any number after the decimal point is truncated.

```
nr1 / nr2 // <-- this part within the calculation is causing the problem.
```

A simple trick which you can do to overcome the problem is to multiply one of the integers `nr1` or `nr2` with `1.0` first then that should produce a double which should allow you to keep the precision because you're dividing by `double` now rather than `int`.

**Example:**

```
System.out.println(Math.round((1.0 * nr1) / nr2 * 10.0)/10.0);
```

Notice the `1.0`

Comment: This was the easiest explanation to make my code work.

Answer (score 2):

Change the line

```
System.out.println(Math.round(nr1 / nr2*10.0)/10.0);
```

To the line

```
System.out.println(Math.round(nr1 / ((double)nr2)*10.0)/10.0);
```

Because when you divide two integers, the answer is always an integer which is always rounder down ((int)2.9 = 2 and (int)3.1 = 3). cast into doubles and then divide in order to get the right answer.

Let's look at the following code:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 3;
System.out.println(a/b);
```

This will print 3, it will not print 3.3333333... that is because when dividing integers the result is always an integer and always rounded down. There are several ways to solve this

```
int a = 10;
double b = 3;
System.out.println(a/b);
```

This will print 3.3333333... because we are no longer dividing 2 integers, one of the variables is a double and therefor the result will be a double

Other ways:

1. Cast into a double:

   ```
   int a = 10;
   int b = 3;
   System.out.println((double)a/b);
   ```
2. Multiplying an integer with a double will result in a double and therefor this will also work

   ```
   int a = 10;
   int b = 3;
   System.out.println(1.0*a/b);
   ```

Notice that this will not work

```
int a = 10;
int b = 3;
System.out.println(a/b * 1.0);
```

This will not work because the division will be calculated before the multiplication and you will get the result 3.0 .

Comment: I really appreciate this kinda of explaining makes lot of sense to me now. Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

Try the following:

```
double nr1 = Integer.parseInt(mataett);
double nr2 = Integer.parseInt(matatva);
```

Comment: The suggestion is OK, but you’re forgetting to explain why it is.